# Resize `textarea` in other directions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a `textarea` and resized it to show just the text `Title 1: value 1;`. Then I selected all the text in the textarea and dragged that text out of it. I noticed that the preview of the text while dragging is identical to the part of the text visible after resizing the textarea. In other words, when dragging the text out, the Chrome browser does not show the whole text, but only the part that is visible in the textarea.

I want to make visible in the textarea only the text `value 1;`. The problem is that the button that resizes the textarea is located at the bottom right of this element. I imagine that if that button was also on the top left of the textarea it would still need to hide the text to the left.

I haven't found a way to resolve this. I also don't know if another html element can replace the textarea to show only the text I need.

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').select()
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 145px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Title 1: value 1; Title 2: value 2;</textarea>
```

Comment: try using executable code snippets showcasing your problem.

Comment: i think you are misusing elements that are meant for a different purpose. you should look for a different approach for the solution. you can use java script or php to output and display your values in different elements as you like.
as far as i know, the function to enlarge text fields comes from the browser and can not be influenced bei css.

Comment: Do you want the rest of the text to remain in that textarea? Sorry, I didn't get it.

Comment: @Ferris Imagine that I want to drag all selected text to the browser's address bar. While dragging text, you can preview part of the text below the mouse cursor. My intention is to visualize only a part of this text that is displayed below the mouse cursor when dragging the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some thought, this might be a solution for you (your last comment also taken into account). **UPDATE:** Fore more flexibility a more appropriate solution has been appended at the end.

The key was to use the `text-indent` property on `<textarea>` and give it a negative value. A few lines of JavaScript are also required (it's self-explanatory since commented). However, it should be mentioned that `width` of `<textarea>` varies as it adapts to the visible text. In order to be able to control this behavior at least somewhat, I've set a `max-width` for `<textarea>`. Furthermore, the value for the `text-ident` has to be adjusted every time the text before the visible text changes.

```js
// required vars
let el, visibleText, visibleTextLength;

// get specific textarea
el = document.querySelector( 'textarea' );

// extract desired text that remains visible
visibleText = el.value.split( ';' )[0].split( ':' )[1];

// get text length of extracted text
visibleTextLength = visibleText.length;

// add the cols attribute to the textarea
el.setAttribute( 'cols', visibleTextLength );

// selects all the text in the textarea
el.select();
```

```css
textarea {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-indent: -70px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Title 1: value 1; Title 2: value 2;</textarea>
```

**UPDATE: A MORE APPROPRIATE SOLUTION**

Due to the `text-indent` dilemma I revised and improved my solution again to get more flexibility. So what changes have been made?

First, **`<textarea>` must now have an `ID` assigned to make things work**. If the `ID` is assigned to an element other than a `<textarea>`, the script exits. Also, an additional CSS part is no longer required to set mandatory style properties. The styling can be handled via script options, but doesn't have to, the old way still works and even has to be used if you want more styling for `<textarea>`. Things like `font-color`, `background-color`, `border` and the like were not taken into account.

If you don't use the script's styling options and create your own CSS rule for `<textarea>` instead, it **MUST** contain and have set the following properties to achieve the desired result:

- `padding` - setting `left` and `right` to `0` is recommended
- `height` - can be customized according to your needs
- `max-width` - set it to `none` if `width` is not an issue
- `line-height` - set to `1` should be fine for general use
- `font-family` - a **monoytpe font** is **highly** recommended
- `font-size` - can be customized according to your needs

Further, as already mentioned, `text-ident` no longer has to be adjusted manually when the length of the "before-text" changes, **where "before-text" is the text before the visible text.** The issue was solved by inserting a temporary `<span>` at the end of the page and placing the "before-text" there. The `width` can now be derived from this and used for the `text-intend`. The `<span>` element is removed from the flow and the `visibility` is set to `hidden` so as not to break the design. Once `width` has been calculated, `<span>` is automatically removed again.

```js
/* Options */

const TxtArea = {
    // textarea element ID (string)
    elID: 'demo-area',
    // text block separator (string)
    txtSep: '; ',
    // sub text separator (string)
    subSep: ': ',
    // cut separator from visible text (bool)
    cutSep: false,
    // invoke event handler only once (bool)
    evOnce: true,
    // event handler trigger (string)
    trigger: 'DOMContentLoaded',
    // textarea styling (object)
    // set <prop>: false to use CSS value
    styles: {
        'padding': '0',             // (string)
        'height': '15px',           // (string)
        'max-width': '100px',       // (string)
        'font-family': 'monospace', // (string)
        'font-size': '14px',        // (string)
        'line-height': '1'          // (string)
    }
};

/* Script */

TxtArea.init = document.addEventListener( TxtArea.trigger, ( event ) => ( ( opts ) => {

    let el,
        elStyle,
        tempElm,
        txtSep = '',
        subSep = '',
        fullText = '',
        firstText = '',
        beforeText = '',
        visibleText = '',
        beforeTextLength = 0,
        visibleTextLength = 0,
        tempElmIdentifier = 'temp-12345678';

    // get specific textarea
    el = document.getElementById( opts.elID );

    // check if it's a textarea
    if ( el.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'textarea' ) {
        console.log( '[ ERROR ] : Custom ID is not assigned to a textarea.' );
        return false;
    }

    // get textarea CSS properties
    elStyle = window.getComputedStyle( el, null );

    // set required properties
    el.style.width = 'auto';
    el.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
    el.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    el.style.resize = 'none';

    // set custom properties
    for ( let property in opts.styles ) {
        if ( opts.styles.hasOwnProperty( property ) && opts.styles[property] !== false ) {
            el.style[property] = opts.styles[property];
        } else {
            el.style[property] = elStyle.getPropertyValue( property );
        }
    }

    // trim separators
    txtSep = opts.txtSep.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g, '' );
    subSep = opts.subSep.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g, '' );

    // get text from textarea
    fullText = el.value;

    // extract first text block
    firstText = fullText.split( txtSep )[0];

    // extract text before visible text
    beforeText = firstText.split( subSep )[0];

    // extract visible text
    visibleText = firstText.split( subSep )[1];

    // get text length of extracted text
    visibleTextLength = visibleText.length;

    // cut separator from visible text
    if ( opts.cutSep === true ) {
        visibleTextLength--;
    }

    // create a temporary element to detect beforeText length
    document.body.appendChild(
        Object.assign(
            document.createElement( 'span' ), {
                id: tempElmIdentifier,
                style: 'position: absolute; visibility: hidden; width: auto; height: auto; white-space: nowrap;',
                innerHTML: beforeText + opts.subSep.replace( / /g, '&nbsp;' )
            }
        )
    );

    // get temporary element
    tempElm = document.getElementById( tempElmIdentifier );

    // assign additional properties
    tempElm.style.zIndex = -9999;
    tempElm.style.left = 0;
    tempElm.style.top = 0;

    // apply required styles from the textarea to the created element
    tempElm.style.fontFamily = elStyle.getPropertyValue( 'font-family' );
    tempElm.style.fontSize = parseFloat( elStyle.getPropertyValue( 'font-size' ) ) + 'px';

    // get beforeText length
    beforeTextLength = tempElm.clientWidth;

    // remove temporary element
    tempElm.remove();

    // adjust textarea's text-indent
    el.style.textIndent = '-' + beforeTextLength + 'px';

    // add cols attribute to the textarea
    el.setAttribute( 'cols', visibleTextLength );

    // select all text within textarea
    el.select();

} ) ( TxtArea ), { once: TxtArea.evOnce } );
```

```css
textarea {
    /* additional styling goes here */
}
```

```html
<textarea id="demo-area">Titel 1: value 1; Title 2: value 2;</textarea>
```